# How to get the latest historical path of QFileDialog

Tags: c++, qt, file-io

I am working on Qt 4.8.5 with Windows 7, and I have a `SLOT` that calls a modal `QFileDialog`, which is just like:

```
QFileDialog fileDialog(this);
fileDialog.setFileMode(QFileDialog::Directory);
if (fileDialog.exec()) {
    // blah blah
}
```

I've noticed that `QFileDialog` automatically keeps the recent path, and whenever it has been constructed, it's able to display the latest path even if I restart the main program.

But I have no idea about where Qt saves the status, and I'd like to get the latest path as a `QString` without opening a `QFileDialog`. Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have extracted the code from Qt sources. As you can see, this information is stored in user scoped QSettings. On Windows, it is under the registry key: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Trolltech\OrganizationDefaults\Qt`. And here is the code to use:

```
QSettings settings(QSettings::UserScope, QLatin1String("Trolltech"));
settings.beginGroup(QLatin1String("Qt"));
QByteArray p = settings.value(QLatin1String("filedialog")).toByteArray();

QDataStream stream(&p, QIODevice::ReadOnly);
QByteArray splitterState;
QList<QUrl> bookmarks;
QStringList history;
QString currentDirectory;
qint32 marker;
qint32 v;

stream >> marker
       >> v
       >> splitterState
       >> bookmarks
       >> history
       >> currentDirectory; // <-- The recent path.
```

Please note, that this can be changed in the next Qt versions.

Comment: Do I have to access the current dir though the registry key? I was expecting something easier... :(

Comment: @Tay2510, you do not need to care about the registry. In the given working code sample, the `currentDirectory` is what you need. Just use it as it is.